# How to remove int from arrayList

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int [] random = new int [25];
    int [] masking_array = new int [25];
    int [] array = new int [25];
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number;
    int token = 3;

    for (int x = 0; x<random.length; x++)
    random [x] = x+1;

    int rand;
    for (int x = 0; x<random.length; x++)
    {
      rand = (int)(Math.random()*25);
      while (random[rand] == -1)
      rand = (int)(Math.random()*25);
      if (random[rand] != -1)
      array[x] = random [rand];
      random [rand] = -1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i< 25; i++) 
    {
      masking_array[i] = 0;
    }

    int bombCount = 0;
    while (bombCount <10)
    {
      rand = (int)(Math.random()*25);

      if (masking_array[rand] == 0)
      {
        masking_array[rand] = 1;
        bombCount += 1;
      }
    }

    System.out.println();
    for (int x = 0; x<array.length; x++)
    {
      if ( x % 5 == 0)
      {
        System.out.println();
      }
      System.out.printf("%03d " , array[x]);
    }
    
    String s1 = " ";
    String s2 = "-B-";
    for (int j = 0; j<array.length; j++)
    {
      System.out.println("\nPlease enter a number");
      number = scanner.nextInt();
      for (int x = 0; x<array.length; x++)
      {
        if (number == array[x] && masking_array[x] == 1)
        {
          System.out.println("Boom");
          System.out.println("Token left is: "+(--token));
        }
        else if (number == array[x] && masking_array[x] == 0)
        {
          System.out.println("Good try, proceed next");
          System.out.println("Token left is: "+(++token));
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[current sample code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmFjn.png)

I've attached both my current sample code and source code. How do I remove the number in the array list whenever the user input *the number*. For example, when the user input 020, how do I remove 020 from the array shown. Is it possible to remove it without converting it into string. Hopefully, the question is clear.

Comment: Use an `ArrayList`. You currently are using an **array**. An array has a fixed length, so you can't *remove* a value from an array. For that you use an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone suggested in the comments, `java.util.ArrayList` would be the easiest solution.

Otherwise, below are two easy solutions.

Using a boolean array to keep track of which value has been removed.

```
        //the array
        int[] a = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
        
        //flagging which element is removed.
        boolean[] removed = new boolean[a.length];
        
        //removing value at index 3
        removed[3] = true;
        
        //removing value at index 5
        removed[5] = true;
        
        //printing the content of array a 
        for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
           if (!removed[i]) 
             System.out.print(a[i] + (i<a.length-1 ? ", " : ""));
```

Using Integer array and use the value null for deleted elements.

```
        Integer[] a =  {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
        
        //removing value at index 3 
        a[3] = null;
        
        //removing value at 5 
        a[5] = null;
        
        //printing the content of array a 
        for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
           if (a[i] != null) 
             System.out.print(a[i] + (i<a.length-1 ? ", " : ""));
```

A third solution would require shifting of the values in the array and keeping track of how many values are still in the array.  This is how `java.util.ArrayList` works internally.

```
    static int indexOf(int[] a, int size, int val){
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
          if (val == a[i])
            return i;
        return -1;
    }
    
    static void remove(int[] a, int size, int val){
        int index = indexOf(a, size, val);
        for(int i=index; i<size-1; i++){
            a[i] = a[i+1];
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      
       int[] a = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
       int size = a.length;
       
       remove(a, size--, 3);
       remove(a, size--, 5);
       
       for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
           System.out.print(a[i] + (i<size-1 ? ", " : ""));      
       }
    }
```